# MacGDBp, but better?

Tags: php, macos, gdb

For debugging php code I use MacGDBp but it has its quirks: it shows only the top frame variables of the stack, it sometimes refuses to display any variable at all and last version has decorates the source text with non ascii characters.
Is there any alternative that is native OS X? (ie. *not* Eclipse, I can't stand it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also used MacGDBp and became frustrated with the limitations you mentioned.  While it is not a native app per say, NetBeans 6.5 and higher is free and includes a decent PHP debugger that works with XDebug.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

It is not without it's own set of issues, but it does seem to be more reliable than MacGDBp.

If you are not opposed to paying, the Komodo IDE (My IDE of choice) also has a PHP debugger.

http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide?src=AScom&type=bn&X=HP&campaign=KMD

Also, though slightly off topic, you may find the easy Xdebug FireFox extension useful:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/58688/

Lastly, the XDebug website has a list of additional clients, browser plugins and instructions on how to use them:

http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll start by giving NetBeans a try for PHP, since I already use it for some small time Java dev work.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if your PHP script uses any time of URL rewriting, mod_rewrite, etc. you will want to make sure and read the section "Path Mapping, Debugger Proxy, and Starting a Debug Session on a Custom URL" of the Netbeans PHP docs linked to above.  For my Zend Framework and CodeIgniter sites it was crucial to prevent NetBeans from attempting to automatically launch a browser for me.  Instead, I manually launched FireFox and navigated to the appropriate URL, using the XDebug FireFox extension to trigger the Netbeans PHP Debugger.

Comment: I tried netbeans, and I find the same problem, no variables on any frame context. This made me think the problem must be somewhere else, so I started digging, enable xdebug logging, and I could see from the messages between xdebug and the IDE that is an xdebug problem (all variables were 'unitialized'). Changed xdebug from 2.0.5 into 2.1.0 (latest stable) and now NetBeans *and* MacDBG both show the variables just fine.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux users - http://protoeditor.sourceforge.net/ has a nice lightweight client for Xdebug which is also available as a plugin for Kate (this is not mentioned on the Xdebug site)

Xdebug also runs happily with XAMPP - if you figure out where to put the compiled .so file ;)

There also is an article describing on how to install Xdebug on Linux w/ XAMPP on the SaniSoft blog: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2007/06/23/how-to-install-xdebug-php-extension-for-xampp-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

http://debuggable.com/posts/setting-up-xdebug-on-mac-os-x-or-win32-linux:480f4dd6-0240-4a90-8fa1-4e41cbdd56cb

That helped me a lot. Perhaps it helps you as well.

Edit: By the way, it is a PHP extension. It can be used in competent IDEs including Netbeans, Eclipse, AS Komodo... Oh, and you may use it manually as well by setting a special GET variable (or COOKIE) (see xdebug manual for more info).